# How can one integrate this complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)=\frac{e}{e-z}$. How can one calculate residues and contour integral of this function. I have very few information about contour integration. And does it help to write the function as a power series?

Comment: Integrate over what contour? The form of $f$ suggests some form of $\log$ surely?

Comment: @copper.hat can you give an example on integrating it over some contour?

Comment: Yes, integrated on the contour $\gamma(t) = e^{it}$, $t \in [0, 2 \pi]$ yields zero.

Comment: You need to be more specific, this is a very basic question that is addressed in most complex analysis texts. If you have a specific question please ask, but your question as is is a bit too vague.

Comment: I mean what are the steps of concluding such result as yielding zero from integrating the function on that contour?

Comment: In this case one can find an explicit antiderivative.

Answer (score 1):

If $\gamma $ is any nice contour then $\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz=0$ if $e$ is not inside the contour and $-2\pi i e$ if it is inside the contour. This follows from Residue Theorem since the residue of $f$ at $e$ is $\lim_{z \to e} (z-e)\frac e {e-z}=-e$. [ I said 'nice contour' to indicate that you have to know whether $e$ is 'inside' or outside' it].